Update figure - clear axis including secondary_y
I wrote a small PyQT6 program to get familiar with QT and matplotlib. In a tab, some graphs will be plotted and should be updated in a certain way after a pushButton is clicked. The program works fine until I introduced a secondary_y axis. The plot will still be updated, but the old graph on the secondary_y will not be deleted. I tried self.tab_2_sc.ax2.clear() resp. self.tab_2_sc.ax2.cla() but it has no effect.
class tab_2_Matplot_2(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(311)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(312)
        self.ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(313)
        super(tab_2_Matplot_2, self).__init__(self.fig)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    [...]
    self.tab_2_sc = tab_2_Matplot_2(self, width=15, height=4, dpi=100)
    [...]

    def tab_2_update_plot(self, value):
 
        [...]
        sub_set_D = pd.DataFrame()
        sub_set_B = pd.DataFrame()
        [...]
        
        self.tab_2_sc.ax1.clear()
        self.tab_2_sc.ax2.clear()
        self.tab_2_sc.ax3.clear()
        
        
        sub_set_D.plot(x='Datum', y='absolute',
                         ax=self.tab_2_sc.ax1,
                         legend=True, style='o-', ylabel="[unit]",
                         xlim=xlim
                         )
         
        # 2nd y-axis 
        sub_set_D.plot(x='Datum', y='Relative',
                         ax=self.tab_2_sc.ax1,
                         legend=True, style='x-', sharex=self.tab_2_sc.ax1, ylabel="[%]",
                         secondary_y=True, 
                         xlim=xlim
                         )
        sub_set_D.plot(x='Datum', y='Relative',
                         ax=self.tab_2_sc.ax2,
                         legend=True, style='x-', sharex=self.tab_2_sc.ax1, ylabel="[%]",
                         xlim=xlim
                         )

        sub_set_B.plot(x='Datum', y='value',
                         ax=self.tab_2_sc.ax3,
                         sharex=self.tab_2_sc.ax1,
                         legend=True,  style='o-',
                         xlim=xlim
                         )

I searched the documentation for help, but I couldn't found a solution.
